# Rails 4 Device 3.2 registration with custom attributes, UnknownAttributeError

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

Issue looks simple, drives me up the walls and has cost me weeks of production time so far and i dont see this issue go away anytime soon since it pops up absolutely everywhere where nested attributes come in.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-12 04:56:03 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"afucNMlRRQkgBeKVVwOQxvjtMtvCDPiQLilr7TXXnUg=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test7@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "first_name"=>"test7", "last_name"=>"test7", "preferred_language"=>"en", **"master_data_contact_information"=>**{"contact_email"=>"test7@test.com", "primary_phone_number"=>"23452352345234", "secondary_phone_number"=>"324523453245", "fax_number"=>"23452345234"}, "group_token"=>""}, "commit"=>"Register"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 96ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: master_data_contact_information):
```

How can it be unknown? it is RIGHT THERE.

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password,
  :password_confirmation, :first_name,
  :last_name, :preferred_language,
  :group_token,
  :master_data_contact_information =>
    [:contact_email, :primary_phone_number, :secondary_phone_number, :fax_number ]
 ) }
end
```

---

if i change it to this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password,
  :password_confirmation, :first_name,
  :last_name, :preferred_language,
  :group_token
  ) }
end
```

I get

```
Unpermitted parameters: master_data_contact_information
```

so what is the deal with nested resources and strong parameters?

---

When run in the RubyMine console, it works fine.

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new user: {"email"=>"test5@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
                                                 "first_name"=>"testqr", "last_name"=>"nsdfjkhasdfjk", "preferred_language"=>"en", "group_token"=>"",
                                                 "master_data_contact_information"=>
                                                     {"contact_email"=>"test10@test.com", "primary_phone_number"=>"786789678678",
                                                      "secondary_phone_number"=>"56675675876567", "fax_number"=>"2456246"}}



p = params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name,
                                 :last_name, :preferred_language, :group_token,
                                 :master_data_contact_information => [:contact_email, :primary_phone_number, :secondary_phone_number, :fax_number ]
)
```

all is shiny.

---

I get that the Rails core people wanted to make rails more secure, but this has taken up a lot of my time.

It works really well on simple models, yes.

when things start to get a tiny bit complicated, all hell breaks lose.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `:master_data_contact_information` to `:master_data_contact_information_attributes`

So you have something like this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password,
  :password_confirmation, :first_name,
  :last_name, :preferred_language,
  :group_token,
  :master_data_contact_information_attributes =>
    [:contact_email, :primary_phone_number, :secondary_phone_number, :fax_number ]
 ) }
end
```